# Android up navigation with singleTop

Tags: android, android-navigation

I have a main activity (Activity A) which shows one Event (my App is about events managaement), I need to be able to open 2 other subActivities and being able to navigate "up" to their parent (A) again, like in the diagram

```
                 open                         open
Activity (A)  ----------> SubActivity (B)  ----------> SubActivity (C)
  ^  ^                        |                             |
  |  |                        |                             |
  |  |           Up           |                             |
  |  --------------------------                             |
  |                                    Up                   |
  -----------------------------------------------------------
```

So, I'm triggering this call from any of the subActivities:

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

and to make sure not to reload Activity (A), I'm using `singleTop` in its AndroidManifest definition (so that when returning to it, it will have the same event with the same state I left it with):

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

But the problem is with having a new requirement to open Activity(A) from system notifications with passing an extra value with the `eventId` I want to open, it works fine if I removed the `singleTop` configuration, but with using it, it gives me the previously loaded instance of the activity without even calling its `onCreate` or other similar stuff,

So, what should I do to handle Activity(A)'s sub-navigation along with its notification-navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `android:launchMode="singleTop"` the already existing Activity will not be recreated! Also the lifecycle slightly changes: When you have a already existing Activity opened and try to open a "new instance" from your notification `Activity.onCreate(Bundle)` is not called again. Instead the method `Activity.onNewIntent()` will be called. So you have to override this method in your activity.

```
 @Override
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // Setup your UI Activity, just like you would to in the onCreate() method
}
```

---

Update: to restart the Activity with new Intent:

```
 @Override
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // pass this extra from the notification only to make a new instance
    boolean makeNewInstance = intent.getBooleanExtra("makeNewInstance", false);
    if (makeNewInstance) {
        finish(); // Finish the current activity
        startActivity(intent); // Start new instance by simply using the intent passed as parameter
    } 
}
```

Comment: You raised a good point, but after some trials I found that when calling Activity(A) from system notification it fires `onNewIntent()` but when reading the Extra value I've just passed, it gives me the old value, not the one I've passed from the notification!

Comment: Yes, if you call getIntent() it will return the initial intent (the intent the activity has been created with). The Intent from the notification is passed as parameter in `onNewIntent()` ... you have to set it manually with `Activity.setIntent()` in `onNewIntent()` or you could simply finish the current (already existing) activity  and start a new activity with the passed intent from `onNewIntent()`. This may be useful if you want to display the Anmiation when a new Activity gets started... Otherwise `setIntent()` should work for you

Comment: I think finishing the current & starting a new one with the passed intent would be a good solution (not to get into layout hassle), but how could I do this from within the `onNewIntent()`

Comment: Brilliant, I just made an edit to the answer to make sure not to restart the activity while getting back from subActivities, I've tried it & it is working absolutely fine with me, thanks a lot :) , I'll accept the answer once the edit been approved.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a value to the Activity while opening from system notification and in onCreate make it conditional. Just a wild guess.

Comment: I'm already passing an extra value, but when usint `singleTop` it never reloads the activity, it just shows me the already loaded instance of it

Comment: When it load the activity `onResume()` will be called; can't you modify your activity there accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extend Activity A, so that it can find the event it shall show from how it does now, and, additionally, from the invocation from the notification. Perhaps you can explain how Activity A gets the information about which event to show, then we can help you to extend this to handle invocations from the notification too.